# How do I use `console.log` in conjunction with knockout and subscribe with Knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, console

I'm using Knockoutjs for the first time and I'm having trouble debugging because of my inability to log variables in console. I can see that my JS is loading properly in console, when I enter:

`Home.TwitterFeedComponent` I see an `object` returned. How do I use `console.log` in conjunction with knockout and subscribe?

```
 var Home = Home || {};

var inheriting = inheriting || {};

Home.TwitterFeedComponent = function(attributes) {
  if (arguments[0] === inheriting)
    return;
  Home.OnScreenComponent.call(this, attributes);

  var component = this;  
  var recent_tweets = ko.observableArray();
  var url = 'https://twitter.com/search.json?callback=?';

  this.attributes.twitter_user_handle.subscribe(function(value) {

    var twitter_parameters = {
      include_entities: true,
      include_rts: true,
      from: value,
      q: value,
      count: '3'
    }

    result = function getTweets(){
       $.getJSON(url,twitter_parameters, 
       function(json) {
           console.log(json)
       });
     }  

     console.log(twitter_parameters);

 });
};

Home.TwitterFeedComponent.prototype = new Home.OnScreenComponent(inheriting);
Home.TwitterFeedComponent.prototype.constructor = Home.TwitterFeedComponent;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean, *"use console.log in conjunction with knockout and subscribe?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem in your code, but if you want to log 'Observables', you have to log it as follows:

```
console.log(observableVar());
```

Comment: Anyway to log a value from within HTML? -- Say we have a `foreach` and we want to log `item`...? Is there a `data-bind="call: someFn(item)"` -- `function someFn(item){ return function(){ console.log(item) } }` or perhaps `data-bind="text: console.log(item)"` (ps. <-- won't work ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear as to the exact scope of the question -- however, if like mine, this question is directed toward the use of `console.log` within your HTML.

Here is a little set of code that may help:

```
<div class="tab-content" data-bind="with: ClientSearch.selectedClient">

...

<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: _general, as: 'item' } -->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: eval( 'console.log(\' le item \', item)' )"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>

...

</div>
```

This code simply logs an item inside of a `foreach` to the console.

Hope this helps!